# IOS custom library functions should ignore if dependency framework are not available?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am building a library which has some functions which use `CoreTelephony` and `CoreLocation` library. These functions properly use @try-@catch. Now whoever includes this library has to include these framework in their application in order to use those functions.

What I want: If the person doesn't include these frameworks, these functions should return nil as described below. However, it throws an error indicating necessity to include these frameworks.

```c
+(NSString *)getLocation
{
    @try {
        CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

        locationManager.delegate = self;

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
        // Configure the new event with information from the location

        float longitude=location.coordinate.longitude;
        float latitude=location.coordinate.latitude;

        NSString *location_string=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d,%d",longitude,latitude];

        return location_string;
    }
   @catch (NSException *exception) 
   {
        return @"";
   }
   @finally 
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: Did you change the Status of your linked frameworks as Optional? (You can find the Linked Frameworks and Libraries at the General tab of your target)

Comment: Yes, at the time of compiling this library in the section "Link Binary with Binaries" I select CoreTelephony framework and marked it as "optional". No Luck.

Comment: instead of a try catch you should test with `NSClassFromString(@"CLLocationManager") != nil`. Try catch is always expensive, and in your case maybe dont even work?! Does your Library crash during compile-Time or during runtime?